# how to handle multiple select's selection

Tags: php, html

This supposedly simple but for some reason i cant figure out the value of a multiple select.

Here is an example:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="cars" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="opel">Opel</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Now in the php side i am trying to `echo` or `print_r($_POST['cars'])`;

However it doesnt print an array it only prints one value from the picked options.

Comment: @RafaelBarros -- Post it, tis the answer

Comment: tried did not change anything

Comment: bahh i've added the [] to the wrong field - brain fart on my part .. bah Thanks rafael

Comment: If you do `<select name="cars[]">` and `print_r($_POST);`, what happens`?

Comment: Also, you can replace `multiple="multiple"` with `multiple`.

Comment: @tymeJV, i think with a little of research he could find out by his own. I almost didn't answer. NetaMeta, try a little harder before asking a question. I see your profile and you are quite an "asker".

Comment: @RecoveringSince2003, depends on his doctype.

Comment: @RafaelBarros -- Agreed, PHP is hardly my specialty, but a quick Google search of "multi-select post php" got me there pretty quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `name` of your `<select>` to an array:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <!-- change cars to cars[] -->
    <select name="cars[]" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="opel">Opel</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```